# Does the MSI H55M-E33 motherboard support the xeon L3426?

Tags: hardware

While searching for this myself I found there were quite some other people online searching for the same answer, but nobody replied with their results.

As such, I found it only fair since I have been able to test this, to post my results for others to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own testing, **Yes** the MSI H55M-E33 supports a Xeon L3426 CPU despite the specifications (and even the MSI Support) saying it doesn't.

I have not tested if ECC memory is also supported, and really doubt it is. Nonetheless all other CPU functions (such as virtualization) seem to be detected by the motherboard just fine.

Tested on Motherboard firmware **1.A**, if your motherboard is on a lower version and doesn't detect the CPU, make sure to use your old CPU to flash the motherboard to the latest version before installing the xeon.